# How to add a bindable property in my user control?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, user-controls

So I created an ASP.NET user control that is a simple wrapper around the [bootstrap slider control](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider). Now I want my control to have a public property named `Value` that I could bind to a property of my model, just like I do with `asp:TextBox`:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" Text="<%# BindItem.Name %>" />
```

Can I do the same with my user control?

```
<uc1:Slider runat="server" Value="<%# BindItem.Age %>" />
```

Comment: Have you decorate your property with **[Bindable] attribute** ??

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: Yes. Doesn't appear to make a diff.

Comment: Well When you use the <%# %> syntax, it'll not executed until you databind the control. So can you try this - in Page_Init method - `uc1Id.DataBind()`.

Comment: Got it to work. `DataBind()` call is not necessary. It was actually the body of my `get` and `set` that was causing trouble. Now working like a charm! Thanks for your input.

Comment: Hi, Could you please post your answer if possible. So that in future others (like me) can get some idea. Thank you...

Comment: @KrishnrajRana: Sure. Here's my answer.

Comment: Thank you for that. Just one doubt In this line - `Value="<%# BindItem.Age %>"` - where BindItem is class and Age is its property right ??

Comment: `Age` is a property, yes. But `BindItem` is not the class. This is a built-in object that you have in `FormView` and other data objects when using [ASP.NET Model Binding](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/28/tutorial-series-on-model-binding-with-asp-net-web-forms.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for any future reader, here's a working version of [bootstrap-slider](https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider)'s server-side control. You can drag-n-drop it onto your ASPX page. It has two properties `Value` and `Value2` (for ranges). There is an event `ValueChanged` that will fire when user moves the position of slider. You can attach an event handler to this even just like you do for `Button` control's `Click` event. Last but not the least, I ensured that the control works within `UpdatePanel` too:

**N.B.** This control doesn't try to include the require JS or CSS file, because if user drops multiple instances of the Slider on the page, the output will probably include a copy of CSS and JS file for each instance, which is undesirable. I couldn't figure out how to link a CSS/JS file only if it hasn't already been included in the current page. So just make sure you include those two files in the parent page once for all.

### Markup

```
<div id="<%= this.UniqueID + "_Div" %>">
    <input runat="server" ID="_TextBox" 
        EnableTheming="false" 
        class="slider form-control" 
        style="vertical-align: middle; width: 100%;" 
        data-slider-min="<%# Min %>" 
        data-slider-max="<%# Max %>"
        data-slider-step="<%# Step %>" 
        data-slider-value="<%# Value %>"
        data-slider-precision="<%# Precision %>" 
        data-slider-orientation="horizontal"
        data-slider-selection="after" 
        data-slider-tooltip="show"
        data-slider-range="<%# IsRange.ToString().ToLower() %>" />
</div>
```

### Code-behind

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace YourProjectNameSpace
{
    public partial class Slider : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        public bool IsRange { get; set; }
        public float Min { get; set; }
        public float Max { get; set; }
        public float Step { get; set; }
        public int Precision { get; set; }

        public event Action ValueChanged;

        [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
        public float Value
        {
            get 
            {
                if (IsRange)
                {
                    string[] Vals = (this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] ?? "0,0").Split(',');
                    return float.Parse(Vals[0]);
                }
                else
                    return float.Parse((this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] ?? "0"));
            }

            set
            {
                if (IsRange)
                {
                    string[] CurVals = (this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] ?? "0,0").Split(',');
                    this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] = value.ToString() + ',' + CurVals[1];
                }
                else
                    this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] = value.ToString();
            }
        }

        [Bindable(true, BindingDirection.TwoWay)]
        public float? Value2
        {
            get
            {
                if (IsRange)
                {
                    string[] Vals = (this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] ?? "0,0").Split(',');
                    return float.Parse(Vals[1]);
                }
                else
                    return null;
            }

            set
            {
                if (IsRange)
                {
                    string[] CurVals = (this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] ?? "0,0").Split(',');
                    this._TextBox.Attributes["value"] = CurVals[0] + ',' + value.ToString();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsPostBack)
            {
                if (Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "_TextBox")
                {
                    if (ValueChanged != null)
                        ValueChanged();

                    string MyDivName = this.UniqueID.Replace("$", @"\\$") + "_Div";
                    string SliderVal = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
                    if (IsRange) SliderVal = '[' + SliderVal.Split(',')[0] + ',' + SliderVal.Split(',')[1] + ']';

                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateSliderFor_" + MyDivName,
                    "$('#" + MyDivName + " > input').slider().slider('setValue', " +  SliderVal + 
                    ").on('slideStop', function(slideEvt) { __doPostBack('_TextBox', slideEvt.value); });", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    string MyDivName = this.UniqueID.Replace("$", @"\\$") + "_Div";
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateSliderFor_" + MyDivName, "$('#" + MyDivName + " > input').slider().on('slideStop', function(slideEvt) { __doPostBack('_TextBox', slideEvt.value); });", true);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                string MyDivName = this.UniqueID.Replace("$", @"\\$") + "_Div";
                Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CreateSliderFor_" + MyDivName, "$('#" + MyDivName + " > input').slider().on('slideStop', function(slideEvt) { __doPostBack('_TextBox', slideEvt.value); });", true);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

### Usage

Put this at the top of the page, after `@Page` line:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/Slider.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="Slider" %>
```

Now place Slider control anywhere in the page:

```
<uc1:Slider runat="server" ID="Slider1" Min="10" Max="24" Value="<%# BindItem.Age %>" Step="0.1" Precision="1" IsRange="true" OnValueChanged="Slider1_ValueChanged" />
```

The event handler looks like this:

```
 protected void Slider1_ValueChanged()
 {
      //do whatever you want with Slider1.Value or Slider1.Value2
 }
```